# Publish Messages on Kafka using Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I m currently trying to write a Publisher for Kafka Messages using Spark and Java. The requirement is I will have a Dataset with few records. I need to only publish these records on Kafka queue on a topic.

Following is the publisher code written in Java:

```
    Dataset dataset = messageDataSet.select("value");
    dataset.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
            .write()
            .format("kafka")
            .option("topic","batch")
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","kafka01.qa.com:9092")
            .save();
```

I have added following things is gradle , since the deployment guide of Streaming Kafka Integration says to have the gradle dependecies as provided I have also tried that.

```
dependencies {
compile group: 'com.util', name:'core-utilities-jdk8',version: '0.0.2-spark'
compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.2.8'
compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-s3', version: '1.11.687'
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.9'

compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.12', version: "$sparkVersion"
compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql_2.12', version: "$sparkVersion"
compile group: 'com.databricks', name: 'spark-csv_2.11', version: '1.5.0'
compile group: 'commons-logging', name: 'commons-logging', version: '1.2'

compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11', version: "$sparkVersion"
compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-streaming_2.12', version: "$sparkVersion"
compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12', version: "$sparkVersion"

annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10'
compile group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.10'
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-all', version: '1.10.19'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6'
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-csv', version: '1.7'
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module', name: 'jackson-module-scala_2.12', version: '2.10.1'
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.10.1'
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310', version: '2.10.1'
compile group: 'com.jcraft', name: 'jsch', version: '0.1.55'
}
```

The dependecy I have tried as ProvidedCompile for Kafka and Spark Core but the error continues to be following :

```
User class threw exception: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: 
org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider 
org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider could not be instantiated
at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala:43)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filterImpl(TraversableLike.scala:247)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filter(TraversableLike.scala:259)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:630)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:245)
at com.fileprocessor.jobs.Runner.publishMessage(Runner.java:200)
at com.fileprocessor.SparkFileProcessorMain.main(SparkFileProcessorMain.java:12)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:684)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.$init$(Lorg/apache/spark/internal/Logging;)V
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.<init>(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:44)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
```

I want to simply publish by dataset to Kafka Queues . Spark version is 2.4.4
I have went through the different results of Having transformenrs in Gradle , or downgrading the things for Kafka versions and scala . But nothing has helped . Anyone if have faced similar situation ?

Tried : spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.4 --class com.fileprocessor.SparkFileProcessorMain --master local[*] file-processor-spark-jobs-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Or If any one have anyother way to write the similar code ?

Answer (score 0):

Following gradle worked:

```
dependencies {
compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.2.8'
compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-s3', version: '1.11.687'
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.9'

compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.12', version: "$sparkVersion"
compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql_2.12', version: "$sparkVersion"
compile group: 'com.databricks', name: 'spark-csv_2.11', version: '1.5.0'
compile group: 'commons-logging', name: 'commons-logging', version: '1.2'

compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11', version: "$sparkVersion"
providedCompile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-streaming_2.12', version: "$sparkVersion"
providedCompile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11', version: "2.2.0"

annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10'
compile group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.10'
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-all', version: '1.10.19'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6'
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-csv', version: '1.7'
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module', name: 'jackson-module-scala_2.12', version: '2.10.1'
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.10.1'
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310', version: '2.10.1'
compile group: 'com.jcraft', name: 'jsch', version: '0.1.55'
}
```

And spark submit : spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.0 --class com.fileprocessor.SparkFileProcessorMain --master local[*] file-processor-spark-jobs-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar test bottomline false

Comment: You don't need  --packages if you create an uber jar